# Read/Parse Binary files with Powershell

Tags: parsing, powershell, binary

I'm trying to parse a binary file, and I need some help on where to go. I've looking online for "parsing binary files", "reading binary files", "reading text inside binaries", etc. and I haven't had any luck.

For example, how would I read this text out of this binary file? Any help would be MUCH appreciated. I am using powershell.

[image]

Comment: what are those numbers you get when running [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes ?
I tried to create an empty text file and then read it via [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes. The output was :
255
254
13
0
10
0� ~

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It seems that you have a binary file with text on a fixed or otherwise deducible position. [`Get-Content`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176843) might help you but... It'll try to parse the entire file to an array of strings and thus creating an array of "garbage". Also, you wouldn't know from what file position a particular "rope of characters" was.

You can try .NET classes [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) to read and [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) to decode. It's just a line for each call:

```
# Read the entire file to an array of bytes.
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("path_to_the_file")
# Decode first 12 bytes to a text assuming ASCII encoding.
$text = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes, 0, 12)
```

In your real case you'd probably go through the array of bytes in a loop finding the start and end of a particular string sequence and using those indices to specify the range of bytes you want to extract the text from by the [`GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3.aspx).

The .NET methods I mentioned are available in .NET Framework 2.0 or higher. If you installed PowerShell 2.0 you already have it.

Comment: As an aside, you can convert bytes back to a file with:[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($outputPath, $bytes)

Answer (score 6):

You can read in the file via Get-Content -Encoding byte . I'm not sure how to parse it though.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx doesn't list Encoding as a valid flag anywhere.

Comment: Encodings are for text files, and will break binary files.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Actually you can use -Encoding Byte for reading/writing binary files in PowerShell, REF: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847788(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, have you tried it? It converts every byte into its base-10 string representation when output. (In fact, exactly the same as [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes). Not exactly what's asked for, you have to convert the output first.

Comment: @SilverbackNet: That's the default formatting for console. Try this: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg" -OutFile "D:\logo-w3c-mobile-lg.png";
$sig = (Get-Content -Path "D:\logo-w3c-mobile-lg.png" -Encoding Byte)[0..5];
[String] $decoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($sig);
Write-Host "`$decoded = $decoded";
$sig | Set-Content -Path "D:\logo-w3c-mobile-lg.signature.png" -Encoding Byte;`

Comment: @SilverbackNet: Also try `Get-Content ... -Encoding Byte -Raw` which returns `[System.Byte[]]` instead of `[System.Object[]]` but otherwise is handled exactly the same.

Comment: `byte` isn’t supported in [PowerShell 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6).

Comment: RE comment by Franklin Yu: `byte` isn't supported as of PS6 since, strictly, it is not a **character encoding**. The functionality is still available by specifying `-AsByteStream` instead of `-Encoding`. Reading the entire file into a variable results in an `Object[]` of the bytes (or an actual `Byte[]` if `-Raw` used) which can then be processed as desired. In the example, the *strings* (note the embedded '\0') could be obtained by `-join [char[]]$bytearray[0xe00..0xe11]` and `-join [char[]]$bytearray[0xe13..0xe54]`. The method used rather depends upon what is meant by *parse a binary file*.

Answer (score 6):

If you're just looking for strings, check out the [strings.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439) utility from SysInternals.