# introduce parsing loop / refactor ugly code

Tags: parsing, powershell, automation

I am writing a script that reads from a binary file, converts to ASCII, extracts/delimits 2 columns, and pipes it out to a txt.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10672303/1330266) post to implement the binary > ASCII step, but, in the way that it is implemented in my script, it seems to only perform the above process on the first row in the file.

How would I re-write this to loop through all rows in the file?

My code is below.

```
# run the command script to extract the file
script.cmd

# Read the entire file to an array of bytes.
$bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("filePath")

# Decode first 'n' number of bytes to a text assuming ASCII encoding.
$text = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes, 0, 999999)|

    # only keep columns 0-22; 148-149; separate with comma delimiter
    %{ "$($_[$0..22] -join ''),$($_[147..147]  -join '')"} |

    # convert the file to .txt
    set-content path\file.txt
```

Also, what is a more elegant way of writing this part so it just reads the length of the string, instead of pulling in up to 999999 bytes?

```
$text = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes, 0, 999999)|
```

Comment: If you're assuming it's ASCII encoded data, why do you want to read it as bytes, then convert to text rather than doing ReadAllText to start with?

Comment: @mjolinor - the file starts as binary, then gets converted to ASCII. i am doing this because i want to prevent data corruption when we are pulling the file from FTP in the 1st step in the script.

Comment: Since it's binary data, how are the rows delimited?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think the rows have column delimiters. How would I figure out how the rows are separated though?

Comment: Normally I'd expect to see a newline (13 10) between each row for ASCII data.  You'll need to look at your data.

Comment: @mjolinor - ok, but since i am starting out with binary data, i can't check for a row delimiter before i convert it to ASCII, right? once i convert from binary --> ASCII, i do not see any `#13#10` in the file.

Comment: The 13 and 10 are the binary codes for cr and lf (newline).  You won't see it after it's converted to ASCII, only in the binary.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify index and count. Simply use

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes).Split("`r`n",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

or

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("filePath")).Split("`r`n",[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

I'm not sure why you would want to read it as bytes, when you could simply use `Get-Content`.

Comment: Your 2nd suggestion worked (thank you), but I still need to loop through all rows in the file. Currently only the 1st row is being parsed.

Comment: Didn't see the first question. Since you're extracting text based on character index, you need to loop using `foreach/(%)`. You could use regex instead of character index, but it won't make much difference unless the file is so big that it takes minutes to process. Looping through lines ain't bad. The alternative is reading all the text and then parsing(line by line) which could be slower.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I am very new to the posh game, so i don't know how to implement the loop. I'm still looking around online for how to implement, but if you could show me, I'd geratly appreciate it.

Comment: You're already looping the lines like I would using the `% { }` which is the same as `foreach-object { }`.

Comment: ok, but then why is it only returning the first row in the file? how would i get it to apply the parsing logic to all rows?

Comment: Oh. That's because GetString() returns a single string. I forgot about that. You need to split it into lines before looping it. How the linebreaks are done depends on how the file was created. Try to method above. :)