# Replicate Openssl md5 '-binary' output in powershell?

Tags: openssl, md5, powershell-4.0

I'm unable to reproduce an openssl md5 hash in powershell.  The openssl command to generate the md5 hash uses the '-binary' switch and I do not know what the equivalent function in powershell is.  Is there a way to reproduce openssl's '-binary' switch in powershell?

Openssl:

```
md5="$(openssl md5 -binary < "files/$file" | base64)"
```

Powershell:

```
$md5 = (Get-FileHash $file -Algorithm md5).hash
$md5base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($utf8.GetBytes($md5))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/Parse Binary files with Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672092/read-parse-binary-files-with-powershell). Also see [\[System.IO.File\]::ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on MSDN: *"Opens a binary file, reads the contents of the file into a byte array, and then closes the file..."*